# No Icons Showing Up in Certain Programs in KDE Plasma 5

Tags: arch-linux, kde, icons, plasma5

i installed KDE on Arch Linux and am using the Breeze theme, although no matter what theme or set of icons I choose, icons do not show up in my terminal or file manager, which i believe are from pantheon.

here is an image: 
[image]

Icons show up just fine in oher applications like Firefox and the settings program for KDE Plasma.

Answer (score 0):

[Youtube Video Link how to Change themes and icons in KDE Plasma](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=j7uwpQA_9gU)

[path to breeze-theme default user icon](https://bbs.archlinux.org/viewtopic.php?id=206986)

The icon you are looking for could be available here: `/usr/share/icons/breeze/`

```
export PATH="/usr/share/icons/breeze/:$PATH"
```

[The use of paths in a .desktop file](https://askubuntu.com/questions/722179/icon-path-in-desktop-file)

Icon field is the icon that should be used by the launcher and represents the application. All icons that are under the directory `/usr/share/pixmaps` don't need to have their full path specified, but their filename without the extension. For example, if the icon file is `/usr/share/pixmaps/wallch.png`, then the Icon field should be just 'wallch'. All other icons should have their full path specified.

```
export PATH="/usr/share/pixmaps:$PATH"
```

Comment: talking about the icons used at the top of a window and the ones used by the file manager to represent folders.

Comment: In kde it would be best to right click inside your 'Desktop Folder' and select 'Create New' > 'Link to Application'. From there you can go to the 'Application' tab to enter your own name for the link, and browse for the application in the 'Command' field. You can set the icon by clicking on the question mark icon in the 'General' tab.

Comment: https://ubuntuforums.org/showthread.php?t=1361111

Answer (score 0):

If you're talking about the icons `.desktop` files it means those desktop files don't have an icon set, see dipankar-nalui's answer.

Otherwise, if the application you're using is missing icons and it is a GTK application, be sure you've got the `breeze-gtk` and `kde-gtk-config` packages installed and follow the steps [here](https://wiki.archlinux.org/index.php/KDE#Qt_and_GTK_Applications_Appearance) and [here](https://wiki.archlinux.org/index.php/Uniform_look_for_Qt_and_GTK_applications).

Answer (score -2):

Go to the system settings and select icons (in appearance section) and select any icon.